# TV show about friends traveling to a city in Europe and one transforming into a monster

Tags: story-identification, tv

I can't for the life of me remember the name of a TV series. I saw commercials for it around the time of *Penny Dreadful* in April 2015 while staying in Cuba.

The first episode starts with friends travelling together in either London or Amsterdam or Paris or something. One friend goes missing and then shows up after having no recollection of where he's been. The police think he's part of a terrorist attack or something. I remember it had point of view filming on a camcorder and he met up with this woman who 'changed' him. I don't know if it was a vampire or werewolf.

Answer (score -3):

Don't have enough time to do any research right now, but you might be thinking of "[Resurrection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resurrection_(U.S._TV_series))" It's from 2014-2015, and it aired on ABC.

> The series follows the residents of Arcadia, Missouri, whose lives are upended when their loved ones return from the dead, unaged since their deaths. Among the returned is Jacob Langston (Landon Gimenez), an eight-year-old boy who drowned in 1982. Having been found alive in China, Jacob is brought back to the United States by an immigration agent named J. Martin ("Marty") Bellamy (Omar Epps), who defies orders and returns Jacob to his parents, Henry (Kurtwood Smith) and Lucille (Frances Fisher). Jacob's surprise return inspires his uncle, Arcadia Sheriff Fred Langston (Matt Craven), and Fred's daughter Dr. Maggie Langston (Devin Kelley), whose wife/mother drowned while allegedly trying to rescue the boy, to learn more about this mystery. Caleb Richards (Sam Hazeldine), the father of Maggie's best friend Elaine Richards (Samaire Armstrong), becomes the second Arcadia resident to return, and he warns that there are many more to follow.

Comment: Doesn't look like a match to me, but I add the description of the show for you.